# 2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3634/2019-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Graphic Design is scheduled for an election [next week, August 26](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until August 26 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 8):

What is your relationship, interest and experience in the field of Graphic Design?

Answer (score 5):

GDSE has a few sister sites on the SE network that can be seen as close to our core theme, or at least affiliated.

A few examples:

- [ux.se](https://ux.stackexchange.com), e.g. UI design, usability
- [blender.se](https://blender.stackexchange.com), e.g. 3D design
- [arts & crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com), e.g. print & physical media
- [photography.se](https://photo.stackexchange.com), e.g. post-production
- [computer graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com), e.g. image processing
- the 3D.se proposal was sadly closed

Even the Project Management stack or Stackoverflow can be said to have *something* to do with the graphic design profession.

-

**What is your view on the interaction between our stack and other stacks? Do you think cooperation is necessary, or even viable? How would you approach members of those communities into our community? Would you encourage our members to become active in those communities also?**

Answer (score 5):

*Recycling [my question from last time](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3431/19174):*

A moderator role that is unusually relevant in this community (as opposed to others) is taking “political” initiative, i.e., steering the community by means of meta posts and similar. What are your ambitions in this respect? Are there any pressing issues you would like to address and how do you plan to do so?

Comment: How did this get 2 downvotes? IMO this is the question that would give the most insight on if a candidate has an overall knowledge of our community

Answer (score 5):

*Recycling [my question from last time](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3432/19174) with a bit of specification:*

Name an individual action that showcases your suitability as a moderator, for example an individual meta post, review action, or comment (please provide a link to it). Why do you think that this a good example?

Answer (score 5):

Beyond merely having additional privileges and access on the site, why would you *want* to be a moderator?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 3):

[Recently](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/welcome-to-the-new-graphic-design-stack-exchange), there have been tentative ideas to be more open to Critique questions than we have been in the past. What is your stance on this and the way it is being decided? Were/are there things you would do differently? How would you contribute to this process and discussion?

Comment: I disagree that we have already decided to be more open to critique questions. The requirements for critique questions haven’t changed. If anything, there is a movement to explore this direction, which has yet to see concrete realisation (and in fact, it’s on my mental to-do list to actually do something about this).

Comment: OK, you're right, I'll rephrase the question accordingly.

Comment: I didn't know my post was a proposal.

Comment: OK, what then? An idea, a concept, a brain fart?

Comment: Rants of an ol' timer? Pleas for calm in the face of change? Brain Fart works :)

Answer (score 2):

How many graphic designers does it take to change a lightbulb?

Comment: How big is the committee responsible for ensuring this is completed?

Comment: @Ryan It honestly *is a legitimate question* I'd like nominees to answer.  `:)` (psst.. check rev history)

Comment: Preach it baby. I had upvoted it when I left that comment.

Comment: See and the down voter here *may* be someone not suited to be a moderator :)